# How to open an image and use it with EmguCv/OpenCvSharp in Xamarin Forsm?

Tags: c#, opencv, xamarin.forms, emgucv

I'm developing an app in Xamarin Forms, I need to process images, but I could not do it either OpenCvSharp or EmguCv.

When I try to open the image sending the path, it does not work and crashes:

Here is my code:

```
var file = await CrossMedia.Current.PickPhotoAsync(new PickMediaOptions
            {
                CompressionQuality = 100,
                PhotoSize = PhotoSize.Large
            });    
Mat OriginalImage = new Mat(file.Path, ImreadModes.AnyColor);
```

When I run my app, does not work.

Do you know any solution or any tutorial to follow?

[image]

Comment: what exception causes the crash?

Comment: System.TypeInitializationException
  Message=The type initializer for 'OpenCvSharp.NativeMethods' threw an exception.

Comment: is there an InnerException?

Comment: How could I see the inner exception?

Comment: the exception object has an InnerException property

Comment: I added an image in my description in order to show you, thanks

Comment: from the [docs](https://github.com/shimat/opencvsharp#requirements): "OpenCvSharp won't work on Unity and Xamarin platform."

Comment: you don't say what exactly you're trying to do, but SkiaSharp works on Xamarin

Comment: I'm trying to find corners (Harris detector or anyother). Do you know if i could find corners with it? and how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really familar with OpenCvSharp, but if you want to do it in Emgucv, you can use the following code.

```cs
//Create a string to hold the file location
string fileLocation;

//Create an openfiledialog object to select a photo
OpenFileDialog dialog = new OpenFileDialog
{
    InitialDirectory = Directory.GetParent(Directory.GetParent
        (Environment.CurrentDirectory).ToString()).ToString(),
    Title = "Browse Images",

    CheckFileExists = true,
    CheckPathExists = true,

    FilterIndex = 2,
    RestoreDirectory = true,

    ReadOnlyChecked = true,
    ShowReadOnly = true
};

if (dialog.ShowDialog() == true)
{
    fileLocation = dialog.FileName;

    Mat input = CvInvoke.Imread(fileLocation, ImreadModes.AnyColor);
}
```